# Is there a name for the technique in songs/poems, where the rhyming pattern primes the listener for a certain line, which never comes?

Tags: poetry, humor

Usually used for comedic purposes, for example in Shrek:

> Welcome to Duloc, such a perfect town
>
> Here we have some rules, let us lay them down
>
> Don't make waves, stay in line
>
> and we'll get along fine
>
> Duloc is a perfect place
>
> Please keep off the grass
>
> Shine your shoes, wipe your face

Which begins with an AABB, and subverts the viewer's expectation of "ass", in the final line.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Sean, glad you found us.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].

Comment: "Anti climax" also comes to mind. But since that is what's fun, I guess it's an "Anti climax climax". :)

Comment: On English.se [subverted rhyme](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/102937/48571) is also proposed

Comment: Mr Brightside by the Killers is my favourite mind rhyme - "Now they're going to bed, And my stomach is sick, And it's all in my head, But she's touching his .... chest now..."

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I believe it would just be called a **teasing rhyme**, or more widely a *mind rhyme*. As in the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_rhyme:

> Mind rhyme is the suggestion of a rhyme which is left unsaid and must be inferred by the listener. Mind rhyme may be achieved either by stopping short, or by replacing the expected word with another (which may have the same rhyme or not). Teasing rhyme is the use of mind rhyme as a form of innuendo, where the unsaid word is taboo or completes a sentence indelicately.